# Deserializing a list of objects

Tags: java, serialization

I have file that I need to deserialize with multiple objects of the same type.

```
public static ArrayList<Dog> readDogs() {
    ArrayList<Dogs> dogs = null;
    ObjectInputStream in = null;

    try {
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename)));
        dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();

        while(true) {
            dogs.add((Dog) in.readObject());
        }
    } catch (EOFException e) {

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.toString());   
    } finally {
        try {
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println(e.toString());   
        }
    }
    return dogs;
}
```

With the current implementation, I rely upon a try clause to catch and ignore an end of file exception, this seems pretty ugly but I'm not sure how else to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Don't serialize/deserialize each dog. Serialise/deserialize a single *List* of Dogs.

All List implementations are themselves `Serializable`, and serializing them will automatically serialize all its elements.

Comment: Good Enough, but is there anything we can do for above approach? Or the question itself is not correct?

Comment: @sakura the approach is not correct. OP is reinventing the wheel. Just use the JDK.

Answer (score 0):

`EOFEception` represents an exceptional condition that is caused by something outside of your code. If you are not capturing an `Error` or a `RuntimeException` which represents some bug that you could fix in your code, then using an `Exception` *is* the best way to deal with the problem.

If the problem is not in your code, which is correct, but outside of it (network down, file not found, file corrupted), it is OK and usually recommended to deal with the problems using exceptions.

There are cases where you should validate data before you use it. If there is a large chance of the data being received in an incorrect format (ex: user input), it might be more efficient to validate it first. But in rare cases where you might have a corrupted file among thousands, it's better to catch the exception when it occurs and deal with it.

You could improve your code logging the exceptions, so you can trace them later. You should also consider which class should be responsible for dealing with the exception (if it should catch it and fix the problem, or if it should declare `throws` and propagate it to the caller.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`InputStream.available()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) to test whether data is available in the stream before reading the next dog.

Comment: But it seems even this is not guaranteed to tell you exact picture of available stream, readObject() may fail, right?

Comment: It's not exact. But from what I can tell, you do not need *exact*. Just loop until `InputStream.available()` yields zero.  `InputStream.readObject()` may still fail for reasons other than EOF, but those cases should clearly be dealt with using exception handling.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work:

```
    try {
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(filename);
        in = new ObjectInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(fin));
        dogs = new ArrayList<Dog>();
        while (fin.available() > 0) {
            dogs.add((Dog) in.readObject());
        }
    } catch (EOFException e) {
```

Note that you should call `available()` on the `FileInputStream` object, not the `ObjectInputStream` object, which doesn't properly support it. Note also that you should still catch and handle `EOFException`, since it may still be raised in exceptional situations.

Comment: Calling available results in a zero, therefore the while loop never executes.